# Some git commits are missing after creating git branch from commit id

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am creating a git branch from a commit id, My expectation is it should show commit ids after specified commit id while creating a new branch. But somehow few git commits are missing in the newly created git branch.

I have a main branch which has multiple commits id:

[image: Main Branch commit ids]

I have created a new branch from main branch using `git checkout -b testBranch 3331a4b` command

But when fire `git log --oneline` command on this branch, I can see that some commits ids are missing. Please click on below links to check commit id

testBranch commit ids:
[image: testBranch commit ids]

Missing commit ids of main branch:
[image: Missing commit ids of main branch]

Comment: It smells like the missing commits are on a different branch. Try `git log --oneline --graph --all` to confirm (or contradict) my suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that while `git log --oneline` displays a linear list of commits, commits are not actually linear.  You're expecting that, given some apparently-linear sequence of commits:

```
010 final
009 earlier
008 earlier-still
007 ...
...
001 first
```

that starting from 010 and counting backwards will give you 10 commits, while starting from 009 and counting backwards will give you 9 commits.

That would be true if the commits were linear, but they're not.

The actual numbers are, of course, not sequential, and not decimal—they're hash IDs, like `3331a4b` (which is already short for something much longer that simply *starts with* `3331a4b`).  So you already know you can't just use the number as a simple index.  Let's replace the sequential numbers (001 through 010) or hash IDs (`3331a4b` and such) with single uppercase letters `A` `B` ... `H`, and actually *draw* the commits made in a small repository with ten commits, with the *last* commit being a *merge* commit:

```
A  <-B  <-C  <-D  <-----H
           \           /
            E  <-F  <-G
```

These arrows—the ones coming from `E` pointing to `C` and from `H` pointing to `G` do not have an arrow-tip (because it's too hard to draw in text), but those connectors are arrows as well—allow Git to work backwards from the last commit to the first.

In fact, every Git commit contains some set of *parent commit* hash IDs.  We say that the commit *points to* its parent (with arrows as drawn above).  Most commits have exactly one parent, and these commits form a simple, backwards, linear chain, like that going from `C` back to `A`.  Here, everything is well-behaved: when you start at `C` there is only one path back to `A`.

At least *one* commit, the very first one ever made, has *no* parent hash, because it was the first commit ever made and there is no earlier commit for it to point-to.  This is where the action stops.  Note that the action starts at the *end* and works backwards.

Some commits, like commit `H` in the example above, have *two* parents.  Here, things get tricky, because Git can walk backwards from `H` to *either* `G`, or to `D`.  (You may see where this is going already.)  The `git log` command uses a specific method to linearize its backwards walk, which we will get to in a moment.

A *branch name* like `master` or `develop` actually points to a commit—*one particular* commit—such as commit `H`, so we can draw these things a little more simply, like this, and then add the branch names on the *right*, at the end:

```
A--B--C--D------H   <-- master
       \       /
        E--F--G   <-- develop
```

knowing that the internal links between commits are backwards arrows.  (So as to not require ever *changing* a commit, the arrows themselves are embedded inside the *children*, pointing back to their parent commits—nothing inside a commit can ever move or change; all of a commit's contents are fixed for all eternity.  The children know who their parents are when the children are born, but until the children are born, the parents cannot know who their children will be, so the parents cannot point forward to the children.)

The tricky part here is that the *names*, like `master` or `develop`, *do* move: the name `master` got here by way of a `git merge` command, perhaps run via `git pull`, or perhaps run directly by someone, or via a GitHub "merge pull request" button, or similar.  At some point earlier, the drawing looked like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E--F--G   <-- develop
```

Commit `H` did not yet exist, and starting from `master` and working backwards, `git log` would enumerate commits `D`, then `C`, then `B`, then `A`; starting from `develop` and working backwards, `git log` would enumerate commits `G`, then `F`, then `E`, then `C`, then `B`, then `A`.

At this point, someone ran `git checkout master; git merge develop`, or did something equivalent.  This *created* new commit `H`, pointing back to `G` and `D`, and giving us our now-up-to-date drawing.

Now, suppose that you attach a *new* branch name to commit `F` or `E`.  If you have been viewing `git log` output based on `master`, and have been assuming that commit `D` comes before commit `E`, you might expect to see commits starting from `F` or `E`, working backwards through and including `D`.  But as soon as we draw the *graph* of the commits, and attach a label to `F` or `E`, you will see that we should *not* expect commit `D` to show up:

```
A--B--C--D------H   <-- master
       \       /
        E--F--G   <-- develop
            .
             .....<-- testBranch
```

The fact that `D` is reachable from `H` (`master`, at the moment) does not imply that `D` will be reachable from `testBranch`.

In more complex graphs, the set of commits reachable starting at some branch-tip and working backwards can be much more difficult to see: the graphs become tangled and hard to view or visualize.  Still, using `git log --graph` (with or without `--oneline`) can help here.

#### How `git log` linearizes a nonlinear graph

Since `git log` must show one commit at a time—one per line with `--oneline`, or using more than one output line without it—it needs a queue of *pending commits*.  This queue typically starts out with just the one commit you name:

```
$ git log <hash>
```

or:

```
$ git log <branchname>
```

or with no arguments, the current (`HEAD`) commit.  Git will take the commit out of the queue, show it, then put its parent(s) into the queue.  If the commit just shown is a merge commit, with two (or more) parents, the queue has now become deeper.

Git then takes whichever commit is at the *front* of the queue and shows that commit.  That commit has some parent(s); if the parent(s) have not yet been shown and are not already in the queue, Git puts them into the queue.

The order in which commits are shown is therefore dependent on where they go in the queue.  When the queue is empty—as it often is—and there's only a single parent, that single parent becomes the single entry in the queue, and is immediately shown, removing it from the queue so that the queue is empty again.  This is how a simple linear chain shows up as a simple linear chain: we might put commit `G` in the queue, then take it back out and show it and put `F` in the queue, then take it back out and show it and put `E` in the queue, and so on.

If you start `git log` with *more than one commit:*

```
$ git log master develop
```

(assuming the names `master` and `develop` point to two different commits—it's possible to have two branch names pointing to *the same* commit), the queue will start out with more than one commit in it, so once again, the order of commits *in* the queue will matter.  Git will show the front-of-queue commit first, whether that's the one that `master` names, or the one that `develop` names.  Having shown that commit, Git will insert its parent(s) into the queue if appropriate, and only then have a chance, depending on where the other commit is in the queue now, to show the *other* commit you named on the command line.

The default for queue insertion order is the *commit timestamp*, with a newer (later timestamp) commit going to the front of the queue.  You can control this order to some extent with `--date-order`, `--author-date-order`, `--topo-order`, and `--reverse`.  Using `--graph` forces `--topo-order`.  For details, see [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).